# Selecting averages with limit

Tags: mysql, average

I have a couple of SQL statements that calculate averages within a stored procedure:

```
SELECT AVG(x) INTO _5dayaverage FROM (SELECT x FROM my_data ORDER BY create_date DESC LIMIT 5) AS temptable;
SELECT AVG(x) INTO _10dayaverage FROM (SELECT x FROM my_data ORDER BY create_date DESC LIMIT 10) AS temptable;
```

Is it possible to write these in such a way that I'm only doing a SELECT once instead of making use of a derived table? As I need to calculate averages for 5, 10, 20, 28, 30, 35 and 50 days, it it possible to do all that within a single query instead of doing a SELECT over and over again?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? I don't think it should be tagged both.

Comment: It's MySql, but SQL Server folks can give their input as well.

Comment: Why? If the answer differs for SQL Server, is it going to be valid? Are you going to be able to use the answer that @LeviW posted, for example? If not, you've wasted his time.

Comment: Both have some common grounds don't they? Anyhow, since I'm leaning towards MySql, tag removed.

Comment: Some, yes. But by that extension you could also cast a much wider net, and tag it Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, etc. etc. If I want to know how to fix something on my Mercedes, why would I post to a BMW forum? In case I might hit someone who knows how to fix both?

Comment: I don't see any harm if someone comes up with a solution that could work on both SQL Server and MySql. Stack Overflow isn't here just to get your answer and then it's all forgotten about. It would benefit if someone comes along looking for a SQL Server solution. So there's no time wasted of anyone but you.

Comment: Well Levi posted a solution that works on SQL Server, but you didn't accept that solution or even up-vote it. So I would argue that he did waste his time trying to help you based on your misleading tag. And I've wasted a bunch of time here simply because I watch the sql-server tag and this showed up on my list. If you'd tagged appropriately in the first place, you wouldn't have to deal with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an incrementing variable to get a rownumber in MySQL:

```
SELECT  AVG(CASE WHEN RowNumber <= 5 THEN X END) AS Avg_5,
        AVG(CASE WHEN RowNumber <= 10 THEN X END) AS Avg_10,
        AVG(CASE WHEN RowNumber <= 15 THEN X END) AS Avg_15,
        AVG(CASE WHEN RowNumber <= 20 THEN X END) AS Avg_20,
        AVG(CASE WHEN RowNumber <= 25 THEN X END) AS Avg_25,
        AVG(CASE WHEN RowNumber <= 30 THEN X END) AS Avg_30,
        AVG(CASE WHEN RowNumber <= 35 THEN X END) AS Avg_35
FROM    (   SELECT  @i:= @i + 1 AS RowNumber, x
            FROM    My_Data,
                    (SELECT @i:=0) AS i
            ORDER BY Create_Date DESC
        ) AS Data
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a250/1

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` with a common table expression. Assuming you're using SQL Server 2005+

```
WITH Numbered AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY create_date DESC) AS RowNum,
   X
FROM my_data)

SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN RowNum <= 5 THEN X ELSE NULL END) AS _5_Day_Avg,
   AVG(CASE WHEN RowNum <= 10 THEN X ELSE NULL END) AS _10_Day_Avg
FROM Numbered
```